# android sdk instance could not be loaded. please check your internet connection

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager, avd-manager

Android Emulator in Visual studio can not be loaded without internet connection. Any solution will be appreciated so i can use emulator in visual studio offline.[image]

Comment: Download the required files before going offline. That’s pretty much it.

Comment: try this https://youtu.be/BlLspZB7EvU

Answer (score 39):

For anyone having trouble with this and finding "Visual Studio SDK Manager" and to improve on the other answer (can't comment because I have no reputation):

Go to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager and on the right bottom corner there's a gear, click on Repository and change it to Google.

Comment: here is detailed ans with step, try this https://youtu.be/BlLspZB7EvU

Comment: After battling this really helped me. THANKS!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, and I resolved changing the repository to Google Repository in Visual Studio SDK Manager.